# Creating database dynamically using nodejs in an authenticated environment of mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Started mongod shared instance without keyfile option
Created a user in admin database with all roles and then started the instances with the keyfile option
Using that user we saved a serverside scripting to create a database dynamically.
Then from nodejs we connected admin db and tried executing the serverside script using db.eval
getting the below mentioened error
/home/administrator/Node# node t1.js
open!
Error :null
Error :Error: eval failed: unauthorized

Comment: you should never use db.eval.

Comment: what should I do then?